# Issue in display data with siblings using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Looking for a solution to trigger `$ajax` request and append response data in HTML when time of initial screen load using `onload` event using jquery

Here with my code, PFB

```js
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $(function(){
       $(".clickcounter").each(function(){  
           $(this).parent().addClass('active_parent');         
    var clicked_link = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'URL',
        data : { 'clicked_link' : clicked_link },
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            $('.active_parent .count_span').text(clicked_link+' '+data);
                   $('.active_parent').removeClass('active_parent');
        }
    })
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="size-button-show-code">
 <a class="button-show-code-orng offer-button js-triggers-outclick clickcounter active" href="https://123.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"> Visit HomePage</a>
 <span class="count_span">1st clicks<br></span>
</div>
<div class="size-button-show-code">
 <a class="button-show-code-orng offer-button js-triggers-outclick clickcounter active" href="https://123.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"> Visit HomePage</a>
 <span class="count_span">2nd clicks<br></span>
</div>
<div class="size-button-show-code">
 <a class="button-show-code-orng offer-button js-triggers-outclick clickcounter active" href="https://123.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"> Visit HomePage</a>
 <span class="count_span">3rd clicks<br></span>
</div>
<div class="size-button-show-code">
 <a class="button-show-code-orng offer-button js-triggers-outclick clickcounter active" href="https://123.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer"> Visit HomePage</a>
 <span class="count_span">4th clicks<br></span>
</div>
```

but this code can not find it's nearest `.count_span` and can not add data value in it

can anybody help me with this

Comment: Don't know if this might cause the problem but shouldn't you be doing `$('.count_span').removeClass('active');` instead of `$('.count_span').removeClass('active_span');` ?

Comment: @RafaelDuarte I have just updated my code and I have exactly done that

Comment: Another thing is, the `a` elements already have the `active` class in your html

Comment: @RafaelDuarte please check now

Comment: 1. $(function(){ is shorthand for $(document).ready(function(){ you don't need both
2. Don't make a ajax call inside .each() you only want one request and loop over the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
 $(function(){
  $(".clickcounter").each(function(){
    var $self = $(this);
    $self.parent().addClass('active_parent');         
    var clicked_link = $self.attr('href');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'URL',
      data : { 'clicked_link' : clicked_link },
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        $('.count_span', $self).text(clicked_link+' '+data); // this is where you need $self
        $('.active_parent').removeClass('active_parent');
        //$self.removeClass('active_parent'); is maybe better then they line above -> depends if you really want to remove that class on all element or only the current one
      }
    })
  });
});
```

You need the self reference inside the callback to get the correct count_span element